# Spring Boot Customize ViewResolver for different views. View render for json, xml, pdf, xls

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, xml-parsing

I have two views( Users, Accidents). Build application which working correctly for Users. Where i need to modify like that it work for many of view.

For Json, I am getting result for both view point.

**Its working For:**

localhost:9001/user_data.xml

localhost:9001/user_data.json

localhost:9001/user_data.pdf

localhost:9001/user_data.xls

localhost:9001/accident_data.json

**I want to render data for:**

localhost:9001/accident_data.xml

localhost:9001/accident_data.pdf

localhost:9001/accident_data.xls

As I placed code separately for pdf,xls and xml into corresponding view extended by AbstractView.

I need to update code, Can anyone guide me? Where I collect the view name and modify the response.

**For XML I coded like:**

public abstract class AbstractXmlView extends AbstractView {

```
public AbstractXmlView() {
    setContentType("application/xml");
}

@Override
protected boolean generatesDownloadContent() {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
     response.setContentType(getContentType());
     buildXmlDocument(model, request, response);
     System.out.println(response);

}

public abstract void buildXmlDocument(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response);
```

}

@Component
public class XmlView extends AbstractXmlView{

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void buildXmlDocument(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     response.setContentType("application/xml");
     response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = null;
    try {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Users.class);
        jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); 
        Users users=new Users();
        users.setUser( (List<User>) model.get("users"));
        System.out.println("Users Object: "+users.getUser());
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(users, response.getWriter());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //jaxbMarshaller.marshal(Users, System.out);

}
```

}

Added into resolver:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver xmlViewResolver() {

    return new XmlViewResolver();
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);

    // Define all possible view resolvers
    List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<>();
    resolvers.add(xmlViewResolver());
    resolvers.add(csvViewResolver());
    resolvers.add(excelViewResolver());
    resolvers.add(pdfViewResolver());
    resolvers.add(jsonViewResolver());
    resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
    return resolver;
}
```

Comment: have fount the solution?

Comment: No I haven't found solution.

Comment: I was forced to deal with it on controller level like: @GetMapping(path = "/viewVoteProtocol", produces = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") for MS Word document; I think you would try the corresponding MIME types per contorller method and thus cover each resolver value.